# How to Remove Integers with Dashes from a list while keeping dashes in objects

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list filled with the following strings:

```
    list1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', 05', '101-1', '101-2', 101-3', 
    'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
```

I need to remove both the regular integers as well as the integers with dashes in them while keeping the Names as well as the Names with dashes in them.  I have written the following code so far:

This code removes all of the dashes (but how do I specify only to remove the dashes from the integer strings and not the object strings):

```
list2 = [i.replace('-','') for i in list1 if i.isdigit()]
```

This code removes all integers wrapped in strings:

```
 list3 = [x for x in list2 if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

With the above code, I am able to remove all of the integers, but it also removes all of the 'Names' with dashes in them as well - I need to keep the Names with dashes in them.  How can I do this?

Comment: So the expected output is `['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']`?

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: I think that the easiest way to maintain and change the behavoiuir of such a function would be to use a regex pattern. Are you open for it?

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression - match objects are truthy, `None` is falsy.

```
import re
>>> list1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '101-1', '101-2', '101-3', 
...:         'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
...:         
>>> [x for x in list1 if not re.match(r'\d+(-\d+)?$', x)]
>>> ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/e37swS/1)

(The `^` is not needed in the Python code because `re.match` searches from the beginning of the string.)

Comment: Thank you for your timely response - I realize I need to work on my regex now :)

Answer (score 4):

(Since this is tagged pandas) You can use `str.replace` + `str.isdigit`:

```
s = pd.Series(list1)
s[~s.str.replace('-', '', regex=False).str.isdigit()]

8      Name1
9      Name2
10     Name3
11    Name-4
12    Name-5
13    Name-6
dtype: object
```

To get back a list, call `.tolist()` on the result.

Translating this into pure python, we have the list comp equivalent (look ma, no regex):

```
>>> [x for x in list1 if not x.replace('-', '').isdigit()]
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
```

Comment: Thank you for your timely response - I gave the answer to @timgeb only bc he was first.  But thank you for this wonderful explanation (and no regex :) )

Comment: @thedatasleuth Who you accept is your business, but I strongly advise that you should accept an answer based on whether it was helpful and answered your question and nothing else. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an explicit `for loop` storing the in a variable `res` OR  a `list comprehension`.

```
import re
list1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '101-1', '101-2', '101-3', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
res = []
for val in list1:
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', val):
        res.append(val)
```

If we print `res` we get.

```
>>> res
>>> ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
```

In the case of list comprehension, I would do:

```
[val for val in list1 if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', val)]

>>> ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name-4', 'Name-5', 'Name-6']
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @thedatasleuth, could you do me the favor of up voting my answer since it worked?